# A Cardboard Performance Problem

Tags: google-cardboard

I selected Sony Z1, HTC E9+ and Redmi Note2 for Cardboard App performance test.
Before this test, I supposed the Cardboard App could get the good performance on HTC E9+ (it has a high score on Performance Benchmark).
As below test result, HTC E9+ had the worst result of this test!!!!

[image]

Does anyone have suggestion for this test result?

What's the major factor for the Cardboard App Performance?

---

Test App Description:

Mojing:(Chinese VR App)
http://mj.mojing.cn/

VideoTheater:
This App is implemented by myself.

SimpleVideo Player(a Unity App):
Create a simple VR secne and play a video inside it

VerySimple VR App (a Unity App):
Same as "SimpleVideo Player" but remove the video player

Cardboard Example App@Unity:
Download from Cardboard Developer Web.

Cardboard Example App@Android:
Download from Cardboard Developer Web.

Thanks,
Tony

Comment: Newer phone = better performance (with a specific application)? I'd like to watch a drag race between 2012 Honda Jazz and 1967 Ford Mustang.

Comment: Ford Mustang is a cool car~~ OK, I understand your point. I need to correct the wording >"<.  I supposed HTC E9+ should get the better test result because it has a high score on the "Performance Benchmark". http://blog.gsmarena.com/htc-e9-performance-benchmarks/

Comment: I understand how you think and it is a fallacy called *ceteris paribus*  which means *all else is same*, but it is not! The difference between phones that can affect the results of your test varies from screen resolution to Android version, to chipset, etc. There are a lot. For example, if the phone's screen resolution was halved, it would run with much much better FPS since GPU would have half the work it did before.